# Rspec have_link failing where have_selector passes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have these two tests under requests/pages_spec.rb

**pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Pages" do
    subject { page } 
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "Home page" do
        it { should have_selector('a', text: 'Post your property')}
        it { should have_link('Post your property', href: new_apartment_path)}
    end
end
```

The first test passes and the second one fails saying :

```
expected link "Post your property" to return something
```

This is the html:

```
<a href="/en/apartment/new">Post your property</a>
```

Any idea why the test is failing? Thanks!
Uri

Comment: Are you sure that `new_apartment_path` is set correctly? Being incorrect, the first test would pass and the second would fail as you see.

Comment: I have a :locale prefix to my urls. Maybe that's causing the problem? for instance, in order to user user_path i have to pass it as: user_path (:id => user.id) for it to work. I'm not sure how to do this workaround with the new_apartment_path though...

Comment: Could you run the test `it { should have_link('Post your property', href: "/en/apartment/new")}` to confirm the problem is the `new_apartment_path`?

Comment: the problem is indeed with the new_apartment_path. I'll post my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the context of your `should have_link` is wrong. You could test it by using `save_and_open_page` of the capybara gem like the following code and check the html at that testing point.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Pages" do
    subject { page } 
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "Home page" do
        it { should have_selector('a', text: 'Post your property')}
        save_and_open_page
        it { should have_link('Post your property', href: new_apartment_path)}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! This is what ended up solving it:

The problem was with the named route new_apartment_path not being recognized because of i18n.

What solved it was adding the line:

```
let(:locale) { 'en' }
```

and changing the test to:

```
it { should have_link('Post your property', href: new_apartment_path(locale))}
```